# Tauberian theorem with flatness condition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, tauberian-theorems

Suppose $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is a series with $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and radius of convergence $1$ and such that $f$ restricted to $[0,1[$ admits a smooth extension to $[0,1]$ with $f^{(n)}(1)=0$ for all $n=0,1,\cdots$. Does it follow that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converge? (by Abel necessarily to $0$)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: By the original Tauberian theorem, the question is equivalent to asking is $|a_n|$ is bounded?

I might be overcomplicating things, but I just need this in my research for $f(z)=e^{-\frac{1}{1-z}}$ but the Taylor series didn't seem too helpful.

Comment: for this function, did you try Saddle Point method for computing the Cauchy integrals for the coefficients?

Comment: The function $f(z)=\exp(1/(z-1))$ is bounded on $|z|=1$, so the Cauchy estimates (or rather a limiting version, with $r\to 1$) show that $|a_n|\le C$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov and ChristianRemling, thank you both for your comments. This is enough for my applications. I will leave the question open in case anyone knows the answer for a general function $f$.

Comment: @Christian indeed, but I do not see how does it yield that the series converges

Comment: @FedorPetrov So after thinking about it, first I do need convergence of the series. I thought I could get it using a similar argument but I dont see how. Second, using a taylor series calculator the sum of all terms up to 71 term decreases in absolute value to $1/3e$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Neither do I, but the OP asked about this, so I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: The partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are the coefficients of $f(z)/(1-z)$, but this function is no longer bounded on the unit disc.